# sylow subgroups of GL(n,q)

Tags: finite-groups, reference-request

Dear all

I am interested to know about the r-sylow subgroups of GL(n,q), is there any work about the structure of this subgroups?

Comment: The question (and variants of it) is very broad and comes up a lot, so you should use the search box here and/or try math.stackexchange.com.   Anyway, check out previous questions on MO such as this one (and various answers giving references):

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/88017/

Comment: See in particular Derek Holt's answer to the question linked to by Jim Humphreys.

Answer (score 1):

Quillen's "On the cohomology and $K$-theory of the general linear groups over a finite field".